# Dell Poweredge 2650 RAC Issue

Tags: remote-access, dell-poweredge

I just got a second hand Dell Poweredge 2650 and its working fine.

I can access the embedded remote access controller via the Racadm.exe tool (Under wine) but the web based version of it (Which I would prefer to use) has an SSL certificate error.
I select continue I know there are risks ect and java starts up. It then gives me the error  failed to validate certificate the application will not be executed

Is there any way to be able to fix this?

*Update
Full java error output @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/6352862/

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess - especially as it's a poweredge 2650 - the certificate used to sign the Java applet is expired (and it's Java that's refusing to start). I doubt there's a newer firmware to replace the expired certificate so you're going to have to convince Java to run the signature-expired code.

Comment: So with that in mind it would be helpful if you could update with the exact error message you're receiving from Java.

Comment: Just added to above. About to check if there is newer RAC firmware but the BIOS has been updated to the latest version.

Comment: Newer Java version become pickier and picker. But that's fine and for once I see the world collapsing not Oracle's fault. The guys putting applications (JARs) together without valid signatures and the like should be punished. I'll be interested to find out what that message means, got it several times at other places already.

Comment: I did try to turn java's security for SSL down to the lowest it could as some things recommended when I googled around and nothing. Going to try a few other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's secondhand, have you configured it from scratch?
If not, I would configure it from scratch and see whether you get the same issue.

racadm -r  -u  -p  racresetcfg

Comment: Yes I have already ran that command on it.